# Issue with SleepEx in .NET

Tags: .net, exception, threadpool, sleep

I make use of Wake timers in .NET and in order to make my thread wait till it times out, I use SleepEx through PInvoke. My code is as follows:

```
    private static void SetWaitTimerProc(object state)
    {
        const UInt32 INFINITE           = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        try
        {
            WaitableTimer timer = (WaitableTimer)state;
            long interval       = (long)timer.Interval;
            if (interval != 0)
            {
                TimerAPCProc TimerProc = new TimerAPCProc(TimerProcMethod);
                if (timer.timerHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    bool retVal = SetWaitableTimer(timer.timerHandle, ref interval, 0, TimerProc, IntPtr.Zero, true);
                    uint ret = SleepEx(INFINITE, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Stop();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

        }
    }
```

The wake timer is working fine and there is absolutely no problem with that. But I saw an issue on another machine. The issue is that somewhere at SleepEx I get the following exception through logs:

5/2/2014 5:54:00 PM Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
5/2/2014 5:54:00 PM at Power_Settings.WaitableTimer.SleepEx(UInt32 dwMilliseconds, Boolean bAlertable)
   at Power_Settings.WaitableTimer.SetWaitTimerProc(Object state)

Now I don't understand what can be NULL here? All the values are set perfectly and just to make a note, the SetWaitTimerProc is called using the ThreadPool in .NET as follows:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SetWaitTimerProc),this);
```

Does that have an impact?

EDIT:
I observerd one more interesting thing, TimerProc gets fired when the wait timer elapses while using SleepEx. But as I mentioned earlier, SleepEx throws an exception at times on different machines. So I used the following code and that exception doesn't occur now:

```
        using (EventWaitHandle wh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset))
        {
                        wh.SafeWaitHandle = new Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle(timer.timerHandle, true);
                        wh.WaitOne();
        }
```

But after the WaitOne is released, the TimerProc is not fired. I have to call it manually.

Comment: That's quite hard to tell. When you work with native methods, a lot of things change, and you have to accomodate for that. For example, `TimerProc` might have already been garbage collected, because it isn't used past the `SetWaitableTimer` call. So you'd need to use `GC.KeepAlive` after the `SleepEx` call to make sure it still exists. It's just one of the reasons why you want to avoid doing native interop. `timer` could have already been finalized too. Even `this` could have been collected already, if there's no reference to it :) The point is - why are you using waitable timers?

Comment: Hi @Luaan have a look at few more observations in the EDIT

Comment: @Luaan: I need waitable timers to wake my system up if it supports wake timers so I have to go with it unless there is much better alternative.

Comment: Are you using asynchronous I/O somewhere in your application? `SleepEx` could be awakened by a different IOCP callback, and if it lacks a callback method, it could result in an access violation (.NETs `NullReferenceException` is an access violation with address < 65k). It might very well be that your timer code isn't to blame... Perhaps you shouldn't use ThreadPool threads for things like this? It might be a better idea to create a simple stand-alone `Thread` for the timer...

Comment: Also, in your edited sample, you have not processed the APC, which is why the callback isn't called. If you just call it manually, the APC will remain in the queue forever. Which means that instead calling the callback manually, you need to call `SleepEx(0, true)`, which will get you back to where you started. I've still got the feeling that your callback pointer is actually zeroed out for some reason, either because you're doing asynchronous I/O that at some point ended at the same threadpool thread (weird), or because the GC has reclaimed the delegate already.

Comment: in the edited sample I just replace SleepEx with the EventWaitHandle block. The SetWaitableTimer had reference TimerAPCProc. But it wasn't called.

Comment: The callback isn't called because you haven't processed the APC on the queue. The `SleepEx(0, true)` call is *mandatory*. You can't get around it, that's how you remove (and execute) the callback on the APC queue. MSDN says: `When you are using a waitable timer with an APC, the thread that sets the timer should not wait on the handle of the timer. By doing so, you would cause the thread to wake up as a result of the timer becoming signaled rather than as the result of an entry being added to the APC queue. The thread is no longer in an alertable state and the completion routine is not called.`